# How can I use variable in method function? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, variables, methods

```
let newArr = 0;

function solution(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArr += arr[i];
  }
}

console.log(solution([1,2,3,4])) //undefined ;
```

I want to add all of arrays. But error says, 'newArr' is assigned a value but never used.

How can I use variable in method function?

I tried to declare variable in method.

```
function solution(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let newArr = 0;

    newArr += arr[i];

  }
}
```

Of course it didn't work :(

Comment: function needs to `return` a value (`newArr`)

Comment: You need to return the value from the function. Having said that, if you don't have basic understanding of functions like this, then it'd be worth your time to work through a JavaScript tutorial.

Comment: btw, `newArr` isn't a new array. please use semantic names like `total` or `sum`.

Comment: `const solution = v => v.reduce((a,b)=>a+=b, 0))`

Answer (score 1):

Minimal changes, return `newArr`, though this isn't the cleanest solution

```js
let newArr = 0;

function solution(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArr += arr[i];
  }
  return newArr // add this line
}

console.log(solution([1,2,3,4]))
```

Alternatively, call the function (without a return) then output `newArr` because the function is changing its value. *Global variables like this are generally not good practice, but it does depend on the situation*

```js
let newArr = 0;

function solution(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArr += arr[i];
  }
}
solution([1,2,3,4]) // call function
console.log(newArr) // output the value
```

Define `newArr` in the function and return it

```js
function solution(arr) {
  let newArr = 0; // define local variable

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArr += arr[i];
  }
  return newArr // return value
}

console.log(solution([1, 2, 3, 4]))
// console.log(newArr) // would be undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your function does not return the calculated value after completion.

```
let newArr = 0;
function solution(arr) {
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     newArr += arr[i];
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(solution([1,2,3,4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

function doesn't have return value like you have to check then put console inside that function

**For Exa**

```
let newArr = 0;
function solution(arr) {
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  newArr += arr[i];
}
return newArr;
}

console.log(solution([1,2,3,4]))
```